Is there a unique irreducible polynomial relating two algebraic numbers beyond their minimal polynomials?
Given two algebraic numbers a,b over $\mathbb{Q}$, with $p(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ being the minimal polynomial of $a$, and $q(y) \in \mathbb{Z}[y]$ the minimal polynomial of $b$, suppose that there exists an irriducible polynomial $f(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ such that $f(a,b)=0$, but neither $p(x)$ nor $q(y)$ divides $f(x,y)$. (For example, $a=\sqrt{2}$ and $b=-\sqrt{2}$, then $a+b=0$, but $x^2 -2$ does not divide $x+y$)
Is it then true that such a polynomial $f$ is unique?
In other words, if there is a $g(x,y)$ such that $g(a,b)=0$ and neither $p$ nor $q$ divides $g$, can I conlude that $f$ divides $g$?
I'm searching for a way to find a "minimal polynomial" of two algebraic numbers that gives a releation between them that is not "included" in their minimal polynomials. Also I think that if $a$ and $b$ have different minimal polynomials, then such an $f$ doesn't exist, but I haven't showed that yet.  Any help? Thanks in advance.
Edit: I realized I'm wrong about that last thing, for example $\sqrt{2}$ and $2\sqrt{2}$ have an algebraic relation even tough they have different minimal polynomials. The first question still stands tough.

There is always such an algebraic relation, since $f(x,y) = p(x)-q(y)$ satisfies $f(a,b)=0$.  And clearly $p(x)$ does not divide $p(x)-q(y)$, and $q(y)$ does not divide $p(x)-q(y)$.

I suspect that the condition you should "really" put on $f(x,y)$ is not that it is not a multiple of either $p(x)$ or $q(x)$, but rather that it is not an element of the ideal $(p(x),q(y))$ (that is, it is not of the form $f(x,y)p(x) + g(x,y)q(y)$). (For the previous comment I'm assuming $p\neq q$, as per your penultimate paragraph).

This is more of an extended comment.
I'm going to work throughout in $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$ rather than $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$.
First, I think you are putting the wrong condition on $f$. You should not merely ask that $f$ not be a multiple of $p$ or of $q$; you should really ask that $f$ not be an element of the ideal $(p,q)$. Because note that if $p\neq q$, then $f(x,y) = p(x)+q(y)$ satisfies $f(a,b)=0$, and it is not divisble by $p$ or by $q$, but this is not really a good "relation between $a$ and $b$"; e.g., for $a=\sqrt{2}$ and $b=\sqrt{3}$, we would be saying that $(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ is a zero of $x^2+y^2-5$, and then noting that it is not divisible by either $x^2-2$ nor $y^2-3$.
Second: let $[\mathbb{Q}(a):\mathbb{Q}]=n=\deg(p)$ and $[\mathbb{Q}(b):\mathbb{Q}]=m=\deg(q)$. If $[\mathbb{Q}(a,b):\mathbb{Q}]\lt mn$, then $b$ satisfies an polynomial of degree strictly less than $m$ over $\mathbb{Q}(a)$, and $a$ satisfies a polynomial of degree strictly less than $n$ over $\mathbb{Q}(b)$. So, for example, taking the minimal polynomial of $a$ over $\mathbb{Q}(b)$,  $r(x)\in\mathbb{Q}(b)[x]$ with
$$r(x) = b_0 + b_1x + \cdots + b_{t-1}x^{t-1} + x^t,\qquad t\lt n, b_i\in\mathbb{Q}(b),$$
and $r(a)=0$. Moreover, for each $i$, we can express $b_i$ as a polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[y]$ of degree at most $m-1$ evaluated at $b$. Thus, there exist $\beta_0(y),\ldots,\beta_{t-1}(y)\in \mathbb{Q}[y]$ such that $\beta_i(b)=b_i$, and $\deg(\beta_i)\lt m$. So we can write
$$f(x,y) = \beta_0(y) + \beta_1(y)x + \cdots + \beta_{t-1}(y)x^{t-1}+x^t\in\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$$
with $t\lt n$, $\beta_i(y)$ of degree strictly less than $m$, and such that $f(a,b)=0$.
Note that $f(x,b)\neq 0$.
Does $f(x,y)$ lie in $(p(x),q(y))$?
Assume that $f(x,y)=A(x,y)p(x) + B(x,y)q(y)$.  Then $f(x,b) = A(x,b)p(x) + B(x,b)q(b) = A(x,b)p(x)$.
Since $f(x,b)$ is the minimal polynomial for $a$ over $\mathbb{Q}(b)$, it follows that $f(x,b)$ divides $p(x)$ in $\mathbb{Q}(b)[x]$. So we can find $C(x)\in\mathbb{Q}(b)[x]$ such that $p(x) = f(x,b)C(x)$. Then we have $f(x,b)=A(x,b)p(x) = A(x,b)f(x,b)C(x)$, so $A(x,b)C(x)=1$. Therefore, $C(x)$ is a constant.  But $p(x)$ has degree $n$ in $x$, whereas $f(x,b)$ has degree $t\lt n$. So we cannot have $f(x,y) \in(p(x),q(y))$
Thus, in this situation, there is always a nonzero polynomial $f(x,y)\in\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$ such that $f(a,b)=0$ and $f(x,y)\notin (p(x),q(y))$.
Symmetrically, you can find $g(x,y)\notin (p(x),q(y))$ with the property that $q(a,y)$ is the minimal polynomial of $b$ over $\mathbb{Q}(a)$ and $g(a,b) =0$.
In particular, since $f(a,y)$ has $b$ as a root, we have that $g(a,y)$ divides $f(a,y)$, and symmetrically $f(x,b)$ divides $g(x,b)$.
